# How to massively load attachment files to OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I have on a disk PDF files of previous employee payslips. I would like to load them to OpenERP, as attachments to each employee. Furthermore, I would like to attach more files every month.
To achieve this I want to write a specific module/addon, or a Python program accessing OpenERp through XML-RPC.

How should I interact with the employee model to programmatically attach a file? Is there an ORM method that can be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do more advanced things with attachments, I suggest you check out the [`document`](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/671) module, as well as the [`document_ftp`](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/625) module. They store the attachments in the file system, so you can just copy the files in instead of going through the API. We used the FTP server in OpenERP 5.0, and it worked well for attaching large numbers of files.

Be careful, though. When you install these modules, I think you lose all current attachments. You'll have to migrate those attachments to the file system somehow.

Comment: Are these links dead?

Comment: After 11 years and a name change from OpenERP to Odoo? They're dead, @Johnny. I haven't used the product in years, but my best guess is that the [documents app](https://www.odoo.com/app/documents) is the descendant of the first link. I couldn't immediately find `document_ftp` in the [third-party apps](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules), but that's where I'd look.

Answer (score 0):

Use openerp import / export feature.

Make csv file and then do import.

Comment: base64 encoding using rpc is a good clue; but using GUI import/export, how do you handle file attachments, by filename+address?